# "boost asio address::from_string" invalid argument on "localhost"

Tags: boost-asio

Does anybody know why this gives "Invalid argument" error..

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(address::from_string("localhost"), 8000);`

but below works fine

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 8000);`

I'm using boost 1.67.0

Comment: Because, as the docs say: `Create an address from an IPv4 address string in dotted decimal form, or from an IPv6 address in hexadecimal notation.`. `localhost` is not a `IPv4 address string in dotted decimal form`.

Comment: I see. Should use resolver instead. Thanks.